# Codeigniter Filter Output for URL Use

Tags: php, codeigniter

I may be thinking too much on this, but let's say I have a Website field on database. I've used strip_tags to strip all HTML tags. But if the user inputs this

javascript:alert('test')

It will get passed since it's a string. But then, the HTML will generate

```
<a href="<?php echo prep_url($website);?>">Website</a> //the code in view file
<a href="javascript:alert('test')">Website</a> //bad
```

and the Javascript will execute if clicked. Notice too the prep_url doesn't work.

Any suggestion? I've looked at HTMLPurifier, but it is quite big on size and I don't really want to do some major change.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `strip_tags` if you expect a url, you should validate the URL and probably `urlencode` it. Here's one way with `filter_var`:

```
$url = "javascript:alert('test')";
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
// bool(false)

$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918132";
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
// string(43) "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918132"
```

So if `filter_var($user_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` is `FALSE`, don't accept the user input. This should negate the need for CI's `xss_clean()` although you may want to run it anyways when you put it in the HTML attribute. You may need to run `prep_url` on the input before validating if you don't require the user to enter the `http://` part.

There are many ways to validate a URL, just pick one you like.

Comment: I'm using strip_tags because I don't need the HTML tag, and a URL will be a string right? http://www.google.com won't be affected with strip_tags I think.

I've pondered on filter_var too, I guess I'll create a helper to validate the URL.

What's better though? Let user input whatever they want, and we filter/excape as necessary in the output, or be strict and don't save any input that's not expected?

Comment: It's just unnecessary, and `http://example.com?q=<div></div>` is a valid url which strip_tags would mangle. You just need `urlencode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php As far as your other question: "What's better" depends on what you want to happen. Do you really want to let the user enter junk urls? Then I would use the XSS clean functions or take a second look at HTMLPurifier. In any case, urlencode will take care of stuff that would break your HTML like `"><iframe src=""></iframe><a href="oops`, strip_tags isn't necessary.

Comment: but with urlencode on output, won't valid URL be passed as well? `http://www.google.com` will be encoded and it won't be a valid link anymore right?

Comment: Ah you're right, that doesn't make sense: urlencode shouldn't be run on the whole url. Personally I would use `filter_var`, but if that's not your cup of tea then I would use CI's `xss_clean()` instead since this is the type of thing it's supposed to be designed to protect against. I guess `prep_url` isn't working since `javascript:` *is* technically a valid scheme.

Comment: i kinda took a workaround by extending prep_url and check if the url schema is javascript then return empty. Strangely, I guess CI uses prep_url whenever it inserts/updates database, since whenever I input `javascript:` the field simply is inserted/updated as empty.

CI's xss_clean is another option I guess, though it will generate quite awkward [removed] string in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has an xss filter class. It's not the best thing in the world, but it filters most common problems. [Security class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html)

You can make codeigniter filter all POST and GET by changing the option in your config file, or you can ask to filter manually by doing this.

```
$this->input->post('whatever',TRUE); //Note the TRUE
```